# IRC msg to send to server to send a "whisper" message to a user in channel

Tags: python, protocols, irc

I'm writing up an IRC bot from scratch in Python and it's coming along fine.

One thing I can't seem to track down is how to get the bot to send a message to a user that is private (only viewable to them) but within a channel and not a separate PM/conversation.

I know that it must be there somewhere but I can't find it in the docs.

I don't need the full function, just the command keyword to invoke the action from the server (eg PRIVMSG).

Thanks folks.

Comment: Are you looking for /notice ? (see http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/misc/ccosmos.html#Heading227)

Comment: Not the client commands but the raw command string that client would send to a server. eg to send a PM to a user it would be "PRIVMSG username message" I'm in a place at the moment that doesn't have the ports I need open but I'll try 'NOTICE' later tonight, thanks.

Comment: Too late to edit that reply but the keyword used in the irc protocol itself not the user/client implementation of those commands.

Comment: Home and had a chance to try "NOTICE [user] [message]" and it works, thanks! If you want to make your answer an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for /notice ? (see irchelp.org/irchelp/misc/ccosmos.html#Heading227)